# Wcf service accessing error - The HTTP request was forbidden

Tags: wcf, http, authentication, iis, authorization

When trying to access my WCF service it is throwing following exception

- The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
- Inner Expeption: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Other observations:

- It was working earlier
- Same application when I set up on other system there is not error.
- Using windows application from my system itself it works fine.

Situation:

- WCF service is hosted in remote DEV server and I add as service reference in my web app.
- For now Web app which consumes service is running from VS not by hosting in IIS

A real mess. Did anyone faced such situation? Please share with me. I google about the issue but non of them are helpful.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what type of security bindings you are using?  Windows Auth, Basic, none, etc.

Comment: using default config when a wcf service is reference into a web application. i.e. Windows. With all default setting is it working on other system

Answer (score 0):

It could be that windows authentication is turned on on your local machine but not in IIS.

Double check the app pool your service is running under.  Also, make sure the app pool is running integrated mode and that the version is correct.

See this [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=487) specifically step one.

Comment: Windows authentication is enable in IIS. "Intregrated windows authenticatio" checkbox is checked. in Directory Security tab. Plz check the question again, I added few points

Answer (score 0):

Check the application pool in which the service is hosted. If Windows authentication is turned on over there, then include it in the manifest xml file.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

For Reference : [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)